# Differential of $h(x) = \Vert x \Vert ^4$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

Find the differential of $h: \mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R$ defined as $h(x) = \Vert x \Vert ^4$ (with $\Vert \Vert$ the Euclidean norm).

I'm not sure if I'm correct.
We can write $h(x) = \langle x,x \rangle^2$ with the standard inner product.
To make things easier define $f(x) = \langle x,x \rangle$ and $g(x) = x^2$, with $f : \mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R$ and $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ . $g'(x) = 2x$ and by the product rule $Df_x = 2\langle I,x \rangle$.

$h = g \circ f$ so by the chain rule:
$Dh_x = Dg_{f(x)} \circ Df_x = (2 \langle x,x \rangle) \ \circ \  (2\langle I,x \rangle)$.
Now, $2 \langle x,x \rangle$ is a scalar so I'm not sure if the composition with $Df_x$ should result in the product $4 \langle x,x \rangle \langle I,x \rangle = 4\Vert x \Vert ^2\langle I,x \rangle$, or it should result in $2 \langle 2\langle I,x \rangle,2\langle I,x \rangle \rangle = 8 \langle \langle I,x \rangle,\langle I,x \rangle \rangle = 8 \langle I,x \rangle^2$ since $\langle I,x \rangle$ should result in a scalr when plugging in some vector $v$ (meaning $\langle I,x \rangle(v) = \langle v,x \rangle$).

There might be a simpler way to do this but I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can't you just do it in coordinates: $h(x) = (x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2)^2$?

Comment: Right, I didn't think about that, but honesly this question came up right after we learned about the product rule and the chain rule so I'm interested in understanding how to solve it using them.

Answer (score 2):

$Df_x$ is the linear map that maps $u \in \mathbb R^k$ to $2 \langle u,x \rangle$. $Dg_{f(x)}$ is the linear map that maps $t \in \mathbb R$ to $2 \langle x,x \rangle t$.

As you mentioned, the chain rule states that $Dh_x = Dg_{f(x)} \circ Df_x$. Now take $u \in \mathbb R^k$. We have as seen above $Df_x(u) = 2 \langle u,x \rangle$. Now apply $Dg_{f(x)}$, you get

$$Dh_x(u) =  Dg_{f(x)}(2 \langle u,x \rangle) = 4\langle x,x \rangle \langle u,x \rangle = 4 \lVert x \rVert^2 \langle u,x \rangle.$$

*Note: I don't see the reason to go to coordinates. The way above is valid whatever the dimension of the space and the definition of the inner product are.*

Comment: Thank you! I guess if I think about the maps as matrices it's easier to see it's equivalent to the product of the matrices $Dg_{f(x)}$ and $Df_x$. Also plugging in $u$ also makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Right: avoid coordinates as much as possible.